# Disabled associated products after checking one product

Tags: magento-enterprise

Does anybody encounter in creating configurable product, in associated product tab, when I click one product then rest of the product in non-clickable or disabled?

What's the cause of this? Please help.

Thanks

Here's the example

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alysaa, According configurable logic ,`if you can  not select  same variance valued simple products more than one.`

Suppose , I have a `configurable` products whose `variance  attribute is Color` and have  created one simple `product which color is red` and then after check on this product magento do not `provide to selecting same color simple products`.

If magento id provide this type feature then  same variance option  will show more than one that break the system.

See more details at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product

Comment: Hhmm, I created a set of attribute and add it to the default attributes. I already created 1 configurable product and all of the products I want to put under, I can select all of the products that I want,

In the second time I created a configurable product, I also used the same attributes but I can only select 1 product.

Comment: A simple products  can  be added into other configurable product.

Comment: Hi Amit, I already know the answer I think you're right. I just haven't edit my simple product that has the same variant :) Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome Alysaa :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code template footer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.super-attribute-select:eq(0)','#product_addtocart_form').change(function(){
            var lobj = $(this);

            if(lobj.val()==''){
                $('.super-attribute-select','#product_addtocart_form').find('option').attr('disabled',false).end().val('');
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: add this code template footer